# Unable to get a property set when starting an Android AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

According to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options) and what I've read here on StackOverflow, I am starting an Android emulator with this command from a Shell on MacOS:

```
./emulator -prop myapp.avdname=testing -avd Pixel_2_API_27 -verbose
```

This above code successfully starts the emulator.
I now want to query the property that I set. Again, based on what I've read in the official docs and here on StackOverflow, this terminal command should work:

```
./adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop myapp.avdname
```

But when I run this I don't get anything back. Just a blank line.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer on how to fix this, but I did find the cause. Apparently, an Android avd can have [at most 247 properties](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/eJtg58RvY1M). The defaults for the various avds I have built all try to include at least 247 properties. Additional properties are just ignored.